# cant print the whole array

Tags: java, printing, arrayobject

i need to print an array but it only prints the last info i entered

that's the printing code

```
   for(int i=0; i<undergrad.length;i++){

        if(undergrad[i]!=null){
        System.out.println("Student Name : "+undergrad[i].getName()+"\n"
                + "Full Address : "+undergrad[i].getAddress()+"\n"
                + "Mobile No :"+undergrad[i].getPhone()+"\n"
                + "Number of Tests : "+undergrad[i].getTests()+"\n"
                + "GBA : "+undergrad[i].GBA()+"\n"
                + "Status : "+undergrad[i].computeGrade()+"\n"
                + "Internship : "+undergrad[i].getInternship()+"\n"
                + "Project Title : "+undergrad[i].getProject_Title()+"\n"
                + "Project Area : "+undergrad[i].getProject_Area()+"\n"
                + "Project Score : "+undergrad[i].computeProjectGrade()+"\n"
                + "****************************************\n");

        } 
    }
```

the array of objects is of size 10 but i might put info in less than 10 (for example 4)
and when i print i need to show all and only the 4 i entered

thats the adding part

```
for(int i=0; i<undergrad.length; i++){

    undergrad[i]=new Undergraduate();


    System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
    undergrad[i].setName(in.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Full Address  : ");
    undergrad[i].setAddress(in.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Mobile No : ");
    undergrad[i].setPhone(in.nextLong());

    System.out.println("Number of test : ");
     undergrad[i].setTests(in.nextInt());
    tests=undergrad[i].getTests();

    for(int j=0; j<tests; j++){
        System.out.println("Test "+(j+1)+":");
        undergrad[i].setScores(in.nextInt(), j);
    }

    System.out.println("Internship: ");
    undergrad[i].setInternship(in.nextBoolean());

    in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Project title: ");
    undergrad[i].setProject_Title(in.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Project Area: ");
    undergrad[i].setProject_Area(in.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Supervisor Grade: ");
    undergrad[i].setGrade(in.nextInt(), 0);

    System.out.println("Committee Grade: ");
    undergrad[i].setGrade(in.nextInt(), 1);

    System.out.println("\n");

  break;  
}
```

i need the break because the user should be asked about the action he want to do after entering details about one student (actions like\ writing details for another student or printing the details about the students written  )

Comment: `undergrad[i]` must be `null` in that case. share the code how are you adding the object in array.

Comment: "but it only prints the last info i entered" => because perhaps the rest of it are null.

Comment: honestly I'd just use a `List<UnderGrad> list = new ArrayList<UnderGrad>();` rather than an array.

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you make sure the program has asked you for more than one info in a single run?

Comment: if i dont add break it will ask fo the whole 10 .. and i dont want this to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that the `break;` at the end of your code is needed for the overall code to work, then clearly you are writing to the same array index (0) each time.

The way to fix your program is to remove the `for` loop you currently have and instead keep track of the index `i` in the *outside* loop, the one which offers the user a menu of choices. Then, each time you go to the code which fills a new student, increment your `i` variable.

Keep in mind that, in real code, you would never hit this issue because you would be using a `List<Student>` which automatically takes care about these concerns.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `break;` at the end.
Remove it and it should work.

Comment: yes that's why all objects are `null` in array instead first one.

Comment: Well of course. You break out of the `for` loop on the first run rather than create all 10 elements.

Comment: Your answer implies that when OP refers to the *last info I entered*, he really means *the only info I entered*. If you change that in the question, you have a *completely different* question (and a rather silly one: if that was really the issue, OP would be asking instead "why does my program ask me for only one student?"). So it is highly likely that the `break;` is there by mistake and was not present in the program which motivated this question.

Comment: In that case, he needs to restructure his code to actually *work*, which would mean he doesn't need a for loop, he needs to have a do-while loop in which he modifies the value of the first null element at the input.

Comment: I have finally understood your argument. Yes, the `for` loop must be removed and the `i` index maintained in the outside `while` loop (which he already has).